# Add Month Picker In Xaml Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

I want Only Month And Year Picker In Xaml Silverlight and how to make custom control?

Comment: I am trying below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Calendar control instead you could do,

```
 <sdk:Calendar Height="169" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,48,0,0" Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" DisplayModeChanged="calendar1_DisplayModeChanged" />
```

in code behind,

```
        if (calendar1.DisplayMode == CalendarMode.Month)
            {
                calendar1.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Calendar_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Calendar && e.NewMode != CalendarMode.Year)
                (sender as Calendar).DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
        }
```